# How To Go through a List using keypresses in C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have probably been overthinking it but I am trying to take a list I have and go through the list one by one with a keypress.

For example, I have three strings in a list, and when the player presses L it goes from option 1, to 2. Then 2 to 3. Then 3 to 1. I also need to save this option to a separate string.

Thanks to anyone who can help

Edit:

So I have one script that checks if they key has been pressed

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            gs.ChangeLevel(levelTxt);
        }

    }
```

And then on a different script I have the function that will change the option. I know this isn't correct but hopefully you will be able to see what i am trying to do

````
    public List<String> levels;
    public string level; 
    
     public void ChangeLevel()
        {
        level = levels.Count[]++;   
    
            if(levels.Count > levels.Count)
            {
                levels.Count[0];
            }
    
        }
    
    Edit #2 

    
    So I have almost got it with help from the comments. I just need it to increment now (if this is suppose to it will only stay on the first one)
    
    ```
    public string IncrementLevel()
        {
            if (levels.Count == 0)
            {
                levelIndex = 0;
                return "";
            }
    
            levelIndex = (levelIndex >= levels.Count - 1) ? 0 : levelIndex++;
            return levels[levelIndex];
    
        }
````

And

```
    public void ChangeLevel(Text level)
        {
            level.text = levels[levelIndex].ToString();
            Debug.Log("It is now set to " + levels[levelIndex]);
        }
```

Edit #3

Hey again guys, so the code shared in the comments helped but now I need to take it and decrease it with a different button. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have so far so we can see where it's not working. What do you mean by a "list" in this context? (`List<T>` does not have an "option" property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if we are on the same wavelength, however, if you just want to iterate a list then you need a pointer. You can create a function to increment the pointer and pop the value all in one.

```
private List<string> levels = new List<string>();
private int levelIndex = -1;

public string IncrementLevel()
{
    levelIndex = (levels.Count == 0) ? -1 : (levelIndex >= levels.Count - 1) ? 0 : levelIndex + 1;
    return (levelIndex == -1) ? "" : levels[levelIndex];
}

public string DecrementLevel()
{
    levelIndex = (levels.Count == 0) ? -1  (levelIndex <= 0) ? levels.Count - 1  levelIndex - 1;
    return (levelIndex == -1) ? "" : levels[levelIndex];
}
```

and

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
       gs.ChangeLevel(IncrementLevel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the help you gave me. If I wanted to do the opposite and increment down how would I do that?

Comment: I edited the answer to include a decrement function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
// not tested for compilation, I used 0 as the start 
// since that's the index of the first item in a list

int index = 0;
if (Input.GetKey("L"))
{
  index++;
  if (index > 2)
  {
    index = 0;
  }

  // the item you want is yourList[index], 
  // do whatever you want with it, just make sure 
  // it's used after the if index > 2 statement;
}
```